# Feature Extraction from Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) and use this feature to other classification algorithm

Tags: neural-network

My question is can we use CNN for feature extraction and then can we use this extracted feature as an input to another classification algorithm like SVM.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this has already been done and well documented in several research papers, like [CNN Features off-the-shelf: an Astounding Baseline for Recognition](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.6382) and [How transferable are features in deep neural networks?](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.1792). Both show that using CNN features trained on one dataset, but tested on a different one usually perform very well or beat the state of the art.

In general you can take the features from the layer before the last, normalize them and use them with another classifier.

Another related technique is fine tuning, where after training a network, the last layer is replaced and retrained, but previous layers' weights are kept fixed.